# Getting error while loading the fonts in Expo App

Tags: react-native, expo

I was working on my project & I stuck on loading the Fonts, it gives me a error that this not exists. You can look at the code below;

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

// import { useFonts } from "@use-expo/font";
import {useFonts} from 'expo-font';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading'

import Header from './components/Header';
import EndGameScreen from './screens/EndGameScreen';
import GameScreen from './screens/GameScreen';
import StartGameScreen from './screens/StartGameScreen';

function App() {

  const [userNumber, setUserNumber] = useState();
  const [rounds, setRounds] = useState(0)

  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'Inter-Black': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.tff')
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  }

  const configureNewGameHandler = () => {
    setRounds(0);
    setUserNumber(null);
  };

  const startGameHandler = (selectedNumber) => {
    setUserNumber(selectedNumber);
    setRounds(0);
  }

  const onGameEndHandler = rounds => {
    setRounds(rounds);
  }

  let content = <StartGameScreen onStartGame={startGameHandler}/>;
  
  if (userNumber && rounds <= 0) {
     content = <GameScreen userChoice={userNumber} onGameEnd={onGameEndHandler}/>
  } else if (userNumber && rounds > 0) {
    content = <EndGameScreen 
                roundsNumber={rounds} 
                userNumber={userNumber} 
                onRestart={configureNewGameHandler}
              />
  }
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Header title="Guess a Number" />
      {content}
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1
  }
});
```

Errors that I am getting is shown below;

[image]

Even the path of my local files is correct too, you can see below;

[image]

Can Someone Help me with it, I shall be very thankful to you for this!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the line `'Inter-Black': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.tff')`

replace `.tff` with `.ttf`

P.S. You haven't provided the screenshot with the visible font file names in your file explorer. My answer is based on the fact that the most common font extensions/formats are `.ttf` (TrueType) & `.otf` (OpenType).

Comment: Thanks Bro for pointing out!!! That was a stupid typo mistake & I wasted 1 and half day on it. Thanks Again!!!